# Python 3 equivalence of find()

Tags: python-3.x

I've converted a Python 2 program into Python 3,
but in the following code:

```
te=find(p,']')
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
NameError: global name 'find' is not defined
```

I'm assuming find function is not built-in in Python 3?
What would be the equivalence of my code in Python 3?
Please help me out and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code doesn't even work with python 2.

are you looking for `p.find("]")` ?